# Change CommandField text dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:BoundField HearderText="Name" Datafield="Name"/>
<asp:CommandField HearderText="Name" SelectText="Go" ShowSelectButton="True"/>
```

I want that each `CommandField` takes the data like `DataField`, so instead of "Go", it would have values like, "Jhon", "Mary"...in each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSelect" runat="server" CommandName="Select" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This worked for me